# Group by on 3 table join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Need to use group by on 3 table join. I need to sum price of cars grouped by model and also show what category the model(and car) belongs

**'Accord'** appears 2 times and summed to be 20 , While **'Toyota'** belongs to same model too and summed in same model. And in last '**Bellen'** which only have 1 car. Along with all summed prices and models each model's category is also shown row wise.

[image]

I am joining and summed price as the below query but shows error , which I assume is caused by the third table column which is not been able to grouped according to the condition . How should I get my required result ?

> invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an
>   aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
 SELECT sum(cars.price),models.model,categories.category 
FROM cars 
INNER JOIN 
models 
ON cars.mid=models.id 
inner join 
categories 
on models.model=categories.model 
group by models.model ORDER BY cars.name
```

Comment: you need to group by categories.category or remove the option.  Any column in the select clause must either be an aggregate or indicated in the group by.  Why do you need lines one and two to be diferent if they are the same model and same category

Comment: You are correct I made a mistake there , I need the same model cars price summed together not separately

Comment: Just to clarify, on your image you have a table named car - is it meant to be car or cars?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the table names/column names are correct in your diagram

Data:

```
CREATE TABLE car (price INT, name NVARCHAR(128), mid INT)
GO

INSERT INTO car
VALUES  (10, 'Accord', 1),
        (10, 'Accord', 1),
        (30, 'Bellen', 3),
        (40, 'Toyota', 1)
GO

CREATE TABLE models (id INT, model INT)
GO

INSERT INTO models
VALUES  (1, 1889),
        (2, 1999),
        (3, 2000)
GO

CREATE TABLE categories (model INT, category NVARCHAR(128))
GO

INSERT INTO categories
VALUES  (1889, '800 cc'),
        (1999, '1200 cc'),
        (2000, '1500 cc')
GO
```

Query:

```
SELECT sum(car.price) "Sum Price", models.model "Model", categories.category "Category" 
FROM car 
INNER JOIN models ON car.mid=models.id 
INNER JOIN categories ON models.model=categories.model 
GROUP BY models.model, categories.category
ORDER BY models.model, categories.category
```

Results:

```
Sum Price   Model   Category
60          1889    800 cc
30          2000    1500 cc
```

Comment: Giving erorrs: 
'The multi-part identifier "cars.name" could not be bound.'
'The multi-part identifier "cars.name" could not be bound.'
'The multi-part identifier "categories.category" could not be bound.'

Comment: I edited the answer to remove the group by cars.net - it shouldn't have been there since it wasn't part of the select statement IF you need the car name you should add cars.name in the select statement and keep it in the group by.  Just remember that if it's in the select statement it either HAS to be an aggregate OR in the group by clause - always

Comment: @phpnet could you double check your diagram? Could you confirm table names/column names? Ive tested it using your table names/column names and it works fine